# Could not resolve dependencies for maven project with a dependency (which is a child in a multi maven module project)

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi maven module **project** name customer which has 2 modules in it

1. common-module (it contains DTO, enums)
2. service-module (service logic)

Both, have customer as it's parent and the module uses Maven inheritance.
So hierarchy is

- Customer pom.xml

  - common-module pom.xml
  - service-module pom.xml

**Problem** : When i try to use the dependency of common-module in another **project**  name PROJECT 2 i get below exception

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT 2: Could not resolve dependencies 
 for project PROJECT 2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at 
 com.test:common-module:jar:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
 Could not find artifact com.test:common-module:jar:customer:pom:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

How can i resolve common-module dependency in another project when the common-module uses maven inheritance?

Comment: Where do you deploy your artifacts to?

Comment: in nexus repository

Answer (score 0):

If you execute `mvn install` first on "Customer" project and then also on "PROJECT 2" (on the same machine!), it will work.

If you want to build "PROJECT 2" on a different machine you must configure a server where you deploy (using `mvn deploy`) the jars of "Customer" so that they are available to everyone without recompiling them each time.